# Redirect React form component on submit. React Router v5.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, submit

**The goal** - I have a form that is used to update product details.
I want to redirect to home on form submit.

**The problem** is that I'm sending form data up from my `Form` component to the main `App` component to update the list of products. The products are in my `App` state, and passed as a prop to my `Form`, which causes a re-render of the `Form` component.

`Form` has a flag in state that is set to false in the constructor: `toHome: false`. My plan being to utilise react-router's `Redirect` to fire when the flag is set to true.

In the `EditForm` handleSubmit method there's a `setState({ toHome: true })`. But ALSO in handleSubmit is the method (passed from `App` as a prop) to update the products in `App` state.

**TLDR** -> `Form` handleSubmit updates products -> `Form` re-renders -> redirect flag (`toHome`) set to false in constructor -> redirect never happens.

I have the same problem even if I want to add a short success message. I've been stuck on this for wayyy too long.

`EditForm.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class EditForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      product: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        description: '',
        price: {
          base: '',
          amount: ''
        },
        relatedProducts: []
      },
      productIndex: '',
      toHome: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { productId, allProducts } = this.props
    const thisProduct = this.findProduct(productId, allProducts)
    const thisIndex = this.findIndex(productId, allProducts)

    this.setState({ product: { ...thisProduct }, productIndex: thisIndex })
  }

  .........

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const newAllProducts = this.mergeProducts()
// this is the method that's firing the re-render
    this.props.updateProducts(newAllProducts)
// and here is the ill-fated setState
    this.setState({ toHome: true })
  }

  render() {
    const { id, name, description, price, toHome } = this.state.product
    console.log(this.state.toHome)
    if (toHome) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />
    }

    return (
      <div className="edit-form">
       ....form...
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

EditForm.propTypes = {
  productId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  allProducts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  userCurrency: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  updateProducts: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default EditForm
```

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import ProductList from './ProductList'
import SingleProduct from './SingleProduct'
import Header from './Header'
import EditForm from './EditForm'
import Footer from './Footer'

import allProducts from '../data/products.json'
import '../scss/index.scss'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      selectedCurrency: 'AUD',
      products: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      products: this.getLocalProducts()
    })
  }

  // Checks localStorage for existing product data.
  // If none, initiates localStorage with raw products data
  // and returns raw products to be added to state.
  getLocalProducts() {
    const localData = localStorage.getItem('allProducts')
    if (localData !== 'undefined' && localData !== null) {
      return JSON.parse(localData)
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('allProducts', JSON.stringify(allProducts))
      return allProducts
    }
  }

  // Updates localStorage and state.
  updateProducts = data => {
    localStorage.setItem('allProducts', JSON.stringify(data))
    this.setState({ products: data })
  }

  clearRedirect = () => {
    this.setState({ redirect: false })
  }

  handleCurrencyChange(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedCurrency: e.value })
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedCurrency, products } = this.state

    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="app">
          <Header
            handleChange={e => this.handleCurrencyChange(e)}
            userCurrency={selectedCurrency}
          />
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/products/:id/edit"
              component={({ match }) => (
                <EditForm
                  productId={parseInt(match.params.id)}
                  userCurrency={selectedCurrency}
                  allProducts={products}
                  updateProducts={this.updateProducts}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/products/:id"
              component={({ match }) => (
                <SingleProduct
                  productId={parseInt(match.params.id)}
                  allProducts={this.getLocalProducts()}
                  userCurrency={selectedCurrency}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/"
              exact
              component={() => (
                <ProductList
                  allProducts={products}
                  userCurrency={selectedCurrency}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle or code ?

Comment: Have added code, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `this.props.history.push('/')` to redirect to your homepage instead

Comment: Oh man. I tried this earlier and I got and error `cannot read property 'push' of undefined`, but I've since learned about `react-router-dom`s `withRouther`. 
That did the trick! Thanks so much for the nudge :rocket:

Answer (score 3):

I think there is some clarity needed from you regarding the impl, so please provide a fiddle or something.

In the meantime, what I am guessing is, that you need to redirect on your form submit?

If that is the case,

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

and do

```
  let history = useHistory();
  function handleSubmit() {
    props.handleSubmit() // the one that comes from your App
    history.push("/home");
  }
```

Once you provide more info, I will correspondingly edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've updated with the files in question. 
Since I'm using a class component I can't use hooks :-(